# ROS support for industrial robotic arms?

Tags: ros, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to purchase a 4-6 axis industrial robotic arm with 3 to 6 kg payload and in the $50K range.  Is there ROS support for any from the major manufacturers, e.g. Kuka, Fanuc, ABB, Motoman, or Denso?  Even Linux support would be acceptable and I could develop the ROS software myself.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11585/ros-support-for-industrial-robotic-arms?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Motoman seems to be developing ROS support: http://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/robotics-software/robot-operating-system-making-its-way-into-industrial-robotics

There is also a ROS integration of the KUKA LWR: http://www.ros.org/wiki/lwr_fri

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2011-10-20**:
This is the SWRI project page: http://www.swri.org/4org/d10/msd/automation/ros-industrial.htm - wiki and source is 'coming soon'.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is ROS support for the [Kuka youBot](http://www.youbot-store.com/software.aspx).

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-10-18**:
I wouldn't call the youBot an industrial robot ;) But I have seen the KUKA LWR in a couple of ROS-enabled robots already.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2011-10-18**:
http://youbot-store.com/ybproductinfo.aspx Interesting.  The payload of the arm is far too small to be useful for me but it's nice that it exists.  But it seems like the arm ought to use a similiar interface as  a larger Kuka arm, and there is http://www.ros.org/wiki/ethercat_hardware

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the application or rather how complex is it and what function of the robot controller do you need?

In my application i only need to tell the robotic arm which pose it has to move to and retrieve status values for joints/currentPose/forceValue.

It is probably not a very good solution. At least it is a simple one;). I'm using a tcpConnections to my arm which sends Pose values and gets the status values. This would probably applicable to most other arms that support tcp sockets.

Btw, I’m using a [Universal Robot](http://www.universal-robots.com/).
Unfortunately it's payload is limited to 5 kgs. However the price is definitely less 50k.

---

Originally posted by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) with karma: 174 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2011-10-27**:
Mimax I don't see a private message capability here, but my gmail address is just my user name here backwards (wsacul).

**Comment by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) on 2011-10-26**:
But for my purposes the current solution is fine enough.
One of my co-worker has worked with both robots. I’ll ask him about pros &cons.

**Comment by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) on 2011-10-26**:
As I’m not using all of that fancy motion_planning stuff I’m not sure whether it makes sense to publish such a simple node. I know that the real leverage of ros in terms of hardware integration would be a lower integration of the UR(based on ROS motion_planning).

**Comment by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) on 2011-10-26**:
Unfortunately I don’t have any information online (yet) neither code nor project information, but I can contact you via email. Regarding the ros integration code, as I said, till now it is quite simple. My ROSNode just sends Pose Values to the UR through TCP/IP socket and the UR moves to that pose.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2011-10-26**:
+Brian Gerkey I have word that certification is expected 'early 2012'.  I feel like a lot of the cost of some of the arms are driven by precision/repeatability capabilities I don't require- I think the UR5/6 may be less repeatable than others but that's great for me if it brings the price down.

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-10-24**:
I don't think that Universal is selling arms in the US yet (lacking regulatory certification).  But I'm interested to hear how well it works, and would also like to see a pointer to the ROS integration code.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2011-10-24**:
Actually that might be a very suitable arm.  I haven't heard of this company or the UR5 before but it looks very interesting, is it available in North America?  Do you have any source code available or a project page describing your own work with it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

DENSO is now supported. http://wiki.ros.org/denso

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1